# Launch an application with PowerShell and be able to see it

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, automation

Let's say I have a PowerShell script that remotely launches a desktop application (with a graphic interface) and do something automated.
the application writes the logs etc and I know it works.

I'm currently using a simple `Invoke-Command` and calling the application with API in a scriptblock.

```
Invoke-Command $machine {c:\bat\myautomate.bat}
```

This .bat launches the application.

But how can I see the application? Like … maybe by using a RDP connection?

Comment: You can't remotely invoke an application on someone's desktop via PowerShell remoting. Maybe `PsExec` would work (haven't tried). Why would you need to remotely launch a GUI application anyway?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks for your suggestion. in production we build and package every night a daily version, and we have the virtual machines to test the daily version be installable and usable. so there are automates launch the application and run the scenarios.

Comment: Ansgar is right, `psexec` with the `-i` flag would be fit for purpose. You can find out what session id to use with the `-i` flag by running `query user` and using the value in the ID column.